# Styling certain admin change list rows

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there a straightforward, common way to apply custom styling on admin change list element depending on its properties?

**update**

To be more precise: let's say I have a simple model object.

```
Foo

   field1
   field2
   field3

   @property
    property1()
   @property
    property2()
```

`ModelAdmin.list_display` is defined as a subset of the available fields, so not every attribute (field/property) is displayed in the change list table.

I'd like to apply custom CSS class to the object's row when certain condition is fulfilled, for example: if `foo_instance.property1` is `True` then add class `bar` to the corresponding `tr` element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change row colour in Django Admin List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014914/change-row-colour-in-django-admin-list)

Answer (score 0):

> Now copy the template admin/base_site.html from within the default Django admin template directory (django/contrib/admin/templates) into an admin subdirectory of whichever directory you're using in TEMPLATE_DIRS. For example, if your TEMPLATE_DIRS includes "/home/my_username/mytemplates", as above, then copy django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html to /home/my_username/mytemplates/admin/base_site.html. Don't forget that admin subdirectory.
>
> Note that any of Django's default admin templates can be overridden. To override a template, just do the same thing you did with base_site.html -- copy it from the default directory into your custom directory, and make changes.

from [django's tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/)

Comment: I know about overriding admin templates; the point is I see no way to do this without some deep hacking, since change list uses result_list inclusion tag which returns list o HTML objects (probably formset elements).

Comment: *depending on its properties* @ my question is the key problem here

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by "change list element" and "it's properties"?  Using CSS 2 or CSS 3 selectors you can do some things.  Otherwise, you might be able to do it easily using jQuery (or whatever).  Since it is merely presentation related, I think this would be the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but if you stumble across it, the following tips might be helpful.

You can use [django-liststyle](https://github.com/litchfield/django-liststyle) to customise your admin changelist rows.

It's quite simple to implement your example:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, ListStyleAdminMixin):
    ...
    def get_row_css(self, obj, index):
        if obj.property1:
            return 'bar'
        return ''
```

[Django Suit](http://djangosuit.com/%20Django%20Suit) (not free) also offers "List row and cell attributes" style customisation