# allow_tags=True does not render <form> tag in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to display a form in the list_display in django admin, but I'm facing this problem:

when I define something like this:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('foo', 'pagar_pase')

    def pagar_pase(self, obj):
        return """<form action="." method="post">Action</form> """
    pagar_pase.description = 'Testing form output'
    pagar_pase.allow_tags = True
```

and the result is Action without  tags, any ideas how to solve this?

thanks

Comment: I doubt the problem is what you think it is. `<form>` tags don't have any display output: their only result is to treat the contents as a submittable form. Perhaps you mean to have an `<input type="submit">` tag, although that wouldn't help without something to actually submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the problem here is that list_display is inside an html form, so I was trying to display a form inside a form, that is a bad idea... and below explains why

[Can you nest html forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what appears in the documentation. Few hints:

I think you should include `pagar_pase` in your `list_display` tuple and also you are better off using `format_html` than the triple quotes.

```
from django.utils.html import format_html

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    color_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)

    def colored_name(self):
        return format_html('<span style="color: #{0};">{1} {2}</span>',
                           self.color_code,
                           self.first_name,
                           self.last_name)

    colored_name.allow_tags = True

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'colored_name')
```

Here, they define first the model and then create a `ModelAdmin` and there, they include the method's name in the `list_display` which you're missing.

Your code should be like this:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('foo', 'my_custom_display', 'pagar_pase')

    def pagar_pase(self, obj):
        # I like more format_html here.
        return """<form action="." method="post">Action</form> """
    pagar_pase.description = 'Testing form output'
    pagar_pase.allow_tags = True
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: is not working either, I already edited my question including pagar_pase on list_display and does not work like this way...

Comment: the true problem is that django does not render form tag on list display, even if I use allow_tags=True or format_html, it renders a lot of tags but not form tag

Comment: it makes sense because it is already inside a form. you should try another approach i guess :(

Comment: yep I saw it, but I was expecting for a decent solution here, I'm not sure how to face the problem, the qucik solution would be use jquery to submit data, but it is a paypal form, I will check :(... thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to trigger an action on an item listed.  Perhaps this is better executed by writing your own [admin actions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/).

Here is an example:

```
def pagar_pase(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    """ Does something with each objects selected """
    selected_objects = queryset.all()
    for i in selected_objects:
        # do something with i

pagar_pase.short_description = 'Testing form output'

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('foo', 'my_custom_display')
    actions = [pagar_pase]
```

Comment: with custom admin actions does not work for me, cause I'm trying to render a paypal form on list_display