# Django Admin. How to add background color for each row in list view, when object has boolean field == True?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

My env is: Django 2.0.6, Python 3.6.4

I have standard Django Admin (with inline edit):

[image: standard Django Admin]

How to add background color for each row in list view, when object has field `is_active_city=True`? For example, `background-color: green;` for `is_active_city=True`, like this:

[image: background-color: green]

Comment: An example of how to do this without using a third party app: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4021083/2091925

Comment: @WillKeeling yeah it works great for each individual cell, but not for whole row.

Comment: @Bijoy can you please tell me, do you check works non third party example on Django `2.x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a package [`django-liststyle`](https://github.com/litchfield/django-liststyle) which may satisfy your need

Install it using `pip install django-liststyle==0.2b`

then in settings.py add `'liststyle'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` list.

so now the admin.py for the relevant model would be

```
from liststyle import ListStyleAdminMixin

class CityAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, ListStyleAdminMixin):
    ...
    def get_row_css(self, obj, index):
        if obj.is_active_city:
            return 'green'
        return 'red'  # or any color for False
```

**NOTE**: If there are issues regarding `future` package error, refer this [link](https://github.com/litchfield/django-liststyle/issues/13)

Comment: this package not working in Django `2.x`. Show `TemplateSyntaxError: 'future' is not a registered tag library.`

Comment: But `My env is: Django 2.0.6, Python 3.6.4` as I write in first question. So, `django-liststyle` is not support Python 3.x and/or Django 2.x? Why you recommend it to me?

Comment: The package is python 3 compatible, if it supports python 3 then surely i would recomend it.

Comment: but honestly i didnt check it for `django 2`.

Comment: @VicShóstak can you show me the full traceback of your error

Comment: Yes, I create issue on GitHub project page: https://github.com/litchfield/django-liststyle/issues/14

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172882/discussion-between-bijoy-and-vic-shostak).